# finding the values of json references

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json struct with a few objects that reference each other and I would like the references to the other objects to be replaced with the values of the object. However, I am having trouble changing the values of the json object without specifying it. Is there a way to do this?

Example inputs and outputs of the function:

Input

```
"myData": {
    "reference" : {
        key: "key",
        value: "value"
    }

    "objectOfInterest" : {
        "reference" : {
            key: "key"
        },
        blah: "blah"
    }
}
```

Output

```
"myData": {
    "reference" : {
        key: "key",
        value: "value"
    }

    "objectOfInterest" : {
        "reference" : {
            key: "key",
            value: "value"
        },
        blah: "blah"
    }
}
```

Note: Just to clarify, I do not have trouble finding the reference to replace with. The issue I am having is the actual replacement.

Comment: obvious that `objectOfInterest.reference` is different but phrasing of question is pretty abstract as to what exactly is needed. Please be more precise

Comment: what do you mean "without specifying it"?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has a function **$.extend** for merger object http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

```
    var new_object = $.extend(
        { //Old Object
        "myData": {
            "reference" : {
                key: "key",
            value: "value"
        }

        ,"objectOfInterest" : {
            "reference" : {
                key: "key"
            },
            blah: "blah"
        }
      }
    }, { //New Object Replace

        "objectOfInterest" : {
            "reference" : {
                key: "key2",
                value: "value2"
            },
            blah: "blah"
        }
      }
    );
    console.log(new_object);
```